# Improvements for ugly reflection

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin, gson

I have a project that uses a library to save serialized objects in items and loads them again, when needed.
To do the de-/serialization, this library uses Gson.

Due to how Gson works and how the library is set up, I can't add support for custom types easily and thus have to rely heavily on reflection.
I don't like this, but it has to be like this, sadly.

I am asking, whether there is a way to make this code use more Kotlin idioms.
My issue is that because the fields I am accessing are private, the usual reflection using `::` doesn't work.

Anyways, here is my code:

```
/**
 * Registers a custom GSON handler to handle the [Location] class.
 */
private fun registerGsonHandlers() {
    logger.entering(LobbyMain::class, "registerGsonHandlers")
    // Gets private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    val fGson = NBTReflectionUtil::class.java.getDeclaredField("gson")
    fGson.isAccessible = true

    val modifiersField = Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
    modifiersField.isAccessible = true
    modifiersField.setInt(fGson, fGson.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())

    // Gets  private final List<TypeAdapterFactory> factories;
    val fFactories = Gson::class.java.getDeclaredField("factories")
    fFactories.isAccessible = true
    val factories = fFactories.get(fGson.get(null)) as List<*>

    // Sets private static final Gson gson
    fGson.set(null, GsonBuilder().apply {
        registerTypeAdapter(Location::class.java, LocationTypeAdapter)
        factories.forEach { this::registerTypeAdapterFactory }
    }.create())
    logger.exiting(LobbyMain::class, "registerGsonHandlers")
}
```

It pulls the `Gson` object out of the `NBTReflectionUtil` class, makes it modifiable and gets its list of `TypeAdapterFactories`.
I then create a new `Gson` object with all the old `TypeAdapter`s and mine added and set it as the new `Gson` object for the library.

Answer (score 2):

I'd group your code to make it more readable. Something like this:

```
fun getGson(): Field {
    val fGson = NBTReflectionUtil::class.java.getDeclaredField("gson")
    fGson.isAccessible = true
}

fun removeFinalModifier(field: Field) {
    val modifiersField = Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
    modifiersField.isAccessible = true
    modifiersField.setInt(fGson, fGson.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
}

// etc
```